# How to convert a tuple of references to a reference of a tuple?

Tags: reference, rust

I'd like to convert a tuple of references (which are all references to members of the same struct) to a reference of a tuple.

I've tried to coerce them in various ways, however I wasn't able to do it without cloning.

```rust
struct Bar();

struct Foo(Bar, Bar, Bar);

fn main() {
    let a: &Foo = &Foo(Bar(), Bar(), Bar());
    let b: &(Bar, Bar) = &(a.0, a.1);
}
```

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
 --> src/main.rs:7:28
  |
7 |     let b: &(Bar, Bar) = &(a.0, a.1);
  |                            ^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content

error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
 --> src/main.rs:7:33
  |
7 |     let b: &(Bar, Bar) = &(a.0, a.1);
  |                                 ^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

I expect `b` to be of type `&(Bar, Bar)` given `a` is of type `&Foo`.

Comment: It's highly likely that you are experiencing an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). There's almost certainly a better way to solve the root problem that caused you to ask this question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is impossible.

A reference *refers* to a value. You wish to have a `&(Bar, Bar)` but there is nowhere in memory that has a 2-tuple of `(Bar, Bar)`. You cannot refer to something that does not exist.

The memory layouts of `&(A, B)` and `(&A, &B)` are fundamentally incompatible, so you cannot use unsafe Rust techniques either.

---

In *this particular case*, you **might** be able to use unsafe Rust to convert your `&Foo` directly to a `&(Bar, Bar)`, but...

- it requires that the layout of a tuple struct and a tuple be the same; I don't know that's guaranteed<sup>1</sup>
- it requires that the layout of a tuple struct be tightly packed such that you can offset by the member size to get to the next one; I don't know that's guaranteed<sup>1</sup>
- it requires that the layout of the tuple struct places the members in the same order they are defined; I don't know that's guaranteed<sup>1</sup>
- you can only do it for sequential pieces; no getting the first and third item

```
// I copied this unsafe block from Stack Overflow
// without properly documenting why I think this code is safe.
let b: &(Bar, Bar) = unsafe { &*(a as *const Foo as *const (Bar, Bar)) };
println!("{:?}", b);
```

```
// I copied this unsafe block from Stack Overflow
// without properly documenting why I think this code is safe.
let c: &(Bar, Bar) = unsafe {
    let p = a as *const Foo as *const Bar;
    let p = p.offset(1);
    &*(p as *const (Bar, Bar))
};
println!("{:?}", c);
```

---

**1** — In fact, the [reference explicitly states](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/type-layout.html#tuple-layout):

> Tuples do not have any guarantees about their layout.
>
> The exception to this is the unit tuple (`()`) which is guaranteed as a zero-sized type to have a size of 0 and an alignment of 1.

This means that while this code may print out what you expect and Miri does not complain, it's undefined behavior.

Comment: If the tuple's elements are `Copy`, e.g., `(&usize, &bool)` then it should be copyable as `(*tup.0, *tup.1)`. This can arise when iterating over `HashMap`s, where the key-value pairs are produced as `(&K, &V)` and there's no good way to turn that into a `(K, V)` even when `K` and `V` are `Copy`.

Comment: @BallpointBen yes, but that wouldn't answer the question *How to convert a tuple of references **to a reference of a tuple**?*. That would create an owned tuple. You could then take a reference to that newly created tuple, but it wouldn't work across the iterator chain case you mention as nothing would own the tuple. I agree it would be nice to have a function like `(&A, &B) -> (A, B) where A: Copy, B: Copy` or equivalent for `Clone`, but I'd bet anything like that would wait until something like *variadic tuples* exists.